# How can I get systemd to tell me why init is listening on a particular port?

Tags: debian, systemd, beagleboneblack

I am configuring a BeableBone Black running a Debian image from BeagleBone.org.

I can see that `init` (i.e. systemd) is listening on ports `1880` and `3000`.

```
debian@beaglebone:~$ sudo netstat -taunp | grep LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:53              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      978/dnsmasq         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      852/sshd            
tcp6       0      0 :::53                   :::*                    LISTEN      978/dnsmasq         
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      852/sshd            
tcp6       0      0 :::1880                 :::*                    LISTEN      1/init              
tcp6       0      0 :::3000                 :::*                    LISTEN      1/init
```

Previously, `init` was also listening on port 80.  I disabled that with these commands from https://stackoverflow.com/a/16570889 :

```
systemctl disable bonescript.service
systemctl disable bonescript.socket
systemctl disable bonescript-autorun.service
```

How can I get system to tell me which services are listening on ports `1880` and `3000`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `systemctl list-sockets` and look in the first column, labeled `LISTEN` for something ending in `:3000` or `:1880`. Let us know what you find!

Comment: Thanks.  Appears to be `node-red.socket` and `cloud9.socket`.